# Data structure Graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

given a weighted directed acyclic graph(DAG) G and a vertex s,Dijkstra algorithm with max heap computes the weight of the longest path from s to every other vertex in the graph,
Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm will not work for the next graph:

[image]

Nodes will be analyzed in the following order (`s = 1`):

```
nodes = [1, 3, 4, 2]

distance[1] = 0  
distance[3] = 4  
distance[4] = 7  
distance[2] = 2
```

The longest distance for node `4` is `9` instead of `7`.

Comment: govt plans to build hospitals along the highway from A to B they have identified n locations on the highway where they can build hospitals . let X1 < X2 <...<Xn be the distance of these location from A. they already have one hospital at A and B they want to build minimum number of Hospitals but ensure that the distance from any location on the highway to the nearest hospital is at most K kilometre design an efficient algorithm to solve this problem.analyise your algorithm

Comment: thanks for the above answer,i am facing problem in this too can u help

Comment: @Rahul StackOverflow is not a site to solve your school assignments. Your questions can be removed if that is the case. You need to ask with solutions that you tried along the question.